# Return type is () -> MultipartBody.Part! instead of MultipartBody.Part

Tags: android, kotlin, lambda, rx-java2

I am relatively new to lambda expressions and would love it if somebody could explain why the return type is different from I am expecting. What is `() -> MultipartBody.Part!` anyways?

```
Single.just{
    val file = bitmapToFile(context, fileName, image)
    // create RequestBody instance from file
    val requestFile = RequestBody.create(
        MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data")
        , file
    )

    // MultipartBody.Part is used to send also the actual file name
    return@just MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("picture", file.name, requestFile)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to what @reckter said, which is correct, the return type is a lambda instead of a `MultipartBody.Part` object because of the way you're calling `Single.just`.

More in detail, `Single.just` takes 1 argument of type `T` and returns a `Single<T>`, as described in the [javadoc](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Single.html#just-T-). In your code you're passing a lambda (i.e., something in the form of `{ ... }`) as argument, hence you'll get back a `Single<lambda>`. Note that you can omit the parentheses around the lambda because of [Kotlin syntax](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#passing-a-lambda-to-the-last-parameter). To solve the issue you can slightly change your code:

```
val file = bitmapToFile(context, fileName, image)
// create RequestBody instance from file
val requestFile = RequestBody.create(
    MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data")
    , file
)

val mySingle = Single.just(MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("picture", file.name, requestFile))
```

Comment: The method bitmapToFile has to be called in the background and i was hoping to do the threading using RxAndroid schedulers. Is there a way I can do that and return Multipart.

Comment: You can use a combination of `map` and `subscribeOn`/`observeOn` to run the expensive tasks in a background thread and subscribe on another thread if needed

Answer (score 3):

`() -> MultipartBody.Part` describes a functional type.
It describes a function, that takes in no arguments and returns a `MultipartBody.Part`.
So the compiler is complaining, that you are returning a function, rather than the `MultipartBody.Part`, that it expects.

My guess is, that `Single.just()` does not return `MultipartBody.Part` but rather a function returning that? I am not familiar with the RX framework, so I can not be to sure here.